# iptables rules openwrt not working

Tags: iptables, openwrt

I am new here and I hope find answer to my question
i hvae set rule in openwrt iptables

iptables  -A  FORWARD    -s 192.168.2.14 -m time --timestart 8:00 --timestop 18:30    -j ACCEPT

iptables  -A   FORWARD      -s 192.168.2.14     -j DROP

this rules not worked
but when i have changed to this one it worked

iptables  -A  forwarding_rule    -s 192.168.2.14 -m time --timestart 8:00 --timestop 18:30    -j ACCEPT

iptables  -A  forwarding_rule    -s 192.168.2.14     -j DROP

can any one explain to me the wrong i have done

Answer (score 1):

In OpenWRT you have in default 3 rules:

(you can see this in `iptables -nvL FORWARD`

- rule 1 to move chain to FORWARDING_RULE
- rule 2 accept ESTABLISHED/RELATED packets
- rule 3 REJECT ALL OTHER FORWARD RULE

And Policy about FORWARD is DROP.

When you add:

```
iptables -A FORWARD .....
```

Then this is in the end, after reject. When you add this:

```
iptables -A forwarding_rule ...
```

you add this rule to forwarding_rule chain (in default this chain is empty).

If you would like add to FORWARD you must add this rule before rule number 3 in example:

```
iptables -I FORWARD 1 ...
# or
iptables -I FORWARD 2 ...
# or
iptables -I FORWARD 3 ...
```

```
iptables -I [chain_name] [number] ...
```

then would be works :)

-A add after existing rules, -I add before existing rules

sorry for my bad english... :(

Comment: thanks your are great and your English is very good